# Asp Net Core 3.1 Authorization by Custom Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I've seen basically the same question answered for net core 2.2 on [ASP Net Forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152154.aspx?Configure%20Active%20Directory%20group%20and%20Check%20if%20user%20belongs%20to%20that%20AD%20group%20in%20Net%20CORE%202%202).
When I tried to implement for my net core 3.1 application, I'm getting an error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity'
```

The error happens on the RoleAuthHandler.cs trying to cast Identity to WindowsIdentity.

I'm wondering if there has been change between core 2.2 and 3.1 that explains this or I'm doing something wrong.  Any help would be great.

Startup.cs contains

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleAuthHandler>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        options.AddPolicy(
            Role.Admin,
            policy => policy.AddRequirements(new RoleRequirement(Role.Admin))));
}
```

Role.cs

```
public static class Role
{
    public const string Guest = "Guest";
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
}
```

RoleRequirement.cs

```
public class RoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string[] Roles { get; }

    public RoleRequirement(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.Roles = roles;
    }
}
```

RoleAuthHandler.cs contains

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    RoleRequirement requirement)
{
    var wi = (WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
    var groupSet = new HashSet<string>();

    if (wi.Groups != null)
    {
        foreach (var group in wi.Groups)
        {
            groupSet.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
        }
    }

    string[] userRoles = roleService.GetRolesForGroup(groupSet);
    var intersectRoles = Enumerable.Intersect(userRoles, requirement.Roles, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (intersectRoles.Count() > 0)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Controller class

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class InterestingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Something Interesting";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you check  this line of code var `wi = (WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity` you are supposed to return `ClaimsIdentity` in your cas you need to change your to `wi = (ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity`  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sayah imad - Thanks for the reminder.  I had seen this solution on a post somewhere and dismissed it because the information I was looking for was "what group does the user belong to".  What I didn't realize was that the information was availabile in the ClaimsIdentity.  Your mention, made me think twice about it and I found my answer:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context?.User.Identity;
        var userGroups = claimsIdentity.Claims
            .Where(x => x.Type.Contains("groupsid", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToList();

        if (userGroups == null || !userGroups.Any())
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var groupNames = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var group in userGroups)
        {
            var groupName = new SecurityIdentifier(group.Value)
                .Translate(typeof(NTAccount))
                .ToString();
            groupNames.Add(groupName);
        }

        var userRoles = this.authenticationService.GetRoles(groupNames.ToArray());

        // If the user is an Admin, always allow
        if (userRoles.Contains(Role.Admin))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var intersectingRoles = Enumerable.Intersect(
            userRoles,
            requirement?.Roles,
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (intersectingRoles?.Count() > 0)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue migrating from 2.2 to 3.1, but the `ClaimsIdentity` I'm seeing has an empty `Claims` collection and no `Name`, so how do I get the Windows user info?

Comment: @lesscode I had the same issue as you. I was running an asp.net core web app on IIS, and the web application was configured to accept anonymous authentication. Disabling this, leaving only Windows Authentication available, ensured the claim was one of windows identity.

Comment: @MortenNørgaard Unfortunately our controller has a mixture of authenticated and anonymous endpoints, so we needed both schemes enabled in IIS. I still think this is a breaking change, but we were able to work around the issue by adding code to the top of our custom handler that fails authenticated requests early (causing the challenge back to the client). Details here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/23752#discussioncomment-39900